# Proper way to include PHP files in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, include, format

I am trying to develop a WordPress theme which requires a lot of PHP functions and custom classes.

I am wondering what the best practice is for including additional PHP files within WordPress. Example: Do I list every file to include using:

- include();
- require_once()
- etc

When I review other developers themes I never stumble across a batch of "include() statements, so I believe I must be missing some standard method of performing these includes.

Comment: You may be interested to know common mistakes made in WP Theme Development, see this blog post: http://scriptbaker.com/common-mistakes-in-wordpress-theme-development/

Answer (score 15):

You can follow any method. But I suggest you to use `require` to include any file.

_s ( aka underscores ) which is theme starter kit and default themes of WordPress such as TwentyFourteen, TwentyThirteen, etc are using `require` to include files.

See sample code used in TweentyFourteen theme.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

Comment: If you are doing it for Child theme you need to use stylesheet_directory instead of template_
e.g. require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/folder/file.php';

Answer (score 2):

If you are using child theme and need to load php file from child theme folder, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory()` function. [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

Comment: How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

> Include will include the file content
>
> Require will throw an error if file not found.
>
> Include_once .. check if included if no then include
>
> Require_once same as include_once but with error if file not found

So if you are the one who wrote the file you should include .. not include_once.

We usually, use include for unnecessary files. Require for important files. For example footer.php will not make script stop .. but core.php is important.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all the included files into a single file (library.php) and include that in your theme? By doing this if you need to change something you can change just one file. Also you can use conditional tags like if..else within the library.php to include specific files for certain pages.

I would also suggest that you use require_once() for important files so you get an error if the file is missing. If there is no error when a file is missing then functions that use that file will through multiple errors.

Also as @Othman has suggested you can use include for less important files.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be assigning a
file and include it into your functions.php to avoid redundancy

For Example my functions.php in my root folder
where i get my files from the /inc dir and the functions dir/

```
include('inc/assets.php'); //Where i register all css and js
include('functions/index.php'); // Where are all functions are registered
```

There is also another method on the wordpress codex
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Including_Template_Files

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/blog', 'content'); ?>
```

Also checkout the wordpress organizing theme files docs
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/

```
assets (dir)
      - css (dir)
      - images (dir)
      - js (dir)
inc (dir)
template-parts (dir)
      - footer (dir)
      - header (dir)
      - navigation (dir)
      - page (dir)
      - post (dir)
404.php
archive.php
comments.php
footer.php
front-page.php
functions.php
header.php
index.php
page.php
README.txt
rtl.css
screenshot.png
search.php
searchform.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style.css
```